# Spring - How to implement Single Sign-On with SAML 2.0

Tags: java, security, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, spring-saml

How is SSO with SAML 2.0 typically implemented for a Spring MVC application?

My application is required to implement SSO so the users can log in without creating a new account with my application.

My understanding is that, and correct me if I'm wrong, I need a Service Provider to communicate with the Identity Provider the third party uses in order to exchange the metadata.  But how do I go about to achieve this process?

Also, what is required on the Spring MVC application side?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: You may have a look at this project https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/

Comment: @gusto2 I have looked into the Spring Security SAML project.  However, my question is that I'm not quite sure I have a full understanding of how SSO with SAML 2.0 works yet.  And how is it implemented for a web application?

Comment: Did u get any solution? it will be really helpful for me..

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml implements the SAML SP and integrates into the web app via servlet filters. For SAMLv2 SSO overview look at http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/27819/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.pdf